# Error creating a bean webSecurityConfig through unsatisfied dependency field userDetailsService

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-security, bcrypt, userdetailsservice

I am working on a spring-boot, shopping-cart application.
Everything seems ok, the connection to mysql is working, JDBC is loaded, but i ll always get an exception, i can't find a solution on.

It seems that the [Interface UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) is not properly working. I must say though that i use a deprecated hibernate method [Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) for Pagination Results. Could this be the reason? Help is appreciated after hours of search. I have no clue Thanks....

Exception:

```
2018-03-19 18:44:23.192  WARN 10956 --- [main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountDAO'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' 
defined in com.maxmaxy.mangoshop.SpringBootMangoShopApplication: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: 
Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
Failed to scan classpath for unlisted classes
```

Pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
           8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.
AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.
HttpSecurity;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.
BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import com.maxmaxy.mangoshop.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {

    // Set service to find User in the database & set password encoder
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder = new 
    BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder
    (bcryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  

    http.csrf().disable();

    //Requires login with role EMPLOYEE or MANAGER. If not, will 
    redirect to /admin/login
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/orderList","/admin/order",
    "/admin/accountInfo")
    .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE', 'ROLE_MANAGER'");

    // Pages only for Manager
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/product")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')");

    // When user login, role XX accessDeniedException 
    http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/403");

    //Configuration for login form
    http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
        // Submit the Url
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .loginPage("/admin/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/accountInfo")
        .failureUrl("/admin/login?error=true")
        .usernameParameter("userName")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        // Configuration for the logout page 
       .and().logout().logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
       .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
 }
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority
.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails
.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails
.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.maxmaxy.mangoshop.dao.AccountDAO;
import com.maxmaxy.mangoshop.entity.Account;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private AccountDAO accountDAO;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
    UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account = accountDAO.findAccount(username);
    System.out.println("Account= " + account);

    if (account == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " //
                + username + " was not found in the database");
    }

    // EMPLOYEE,MANAGER,..
    String role = account.getUserRole();

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = 
    new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    // ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_MANAGER
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);

    grantList.add(authority);

    boolean enabled = account.isActive();
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new 
    User(account.getUserName(), //
            account.getEncryptedPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, 
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, grantList);
    return userDetails;
  }
}
```

And the last mentioned class in the exception, AccountDAO:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.maxmaxy.mangoshop.entity.Account;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class AccountDAO {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public Account findAccount(String userName) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.find(Account.class, userName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you try by putting an empty constructor in `UserDetailsServiceImpl` such that, `public UserDetailsServiceImpl(){super();}` and let me know the status.

Comment: Hello @AtaurRahmanMunna, i did, still the same exception:  
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization -

Comment: You should add an annotation `@Component` in `WebSecurityConfig`. Check that if the first error still persist or not `Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': `

Comment: yipp still persists, constructor in UserDetailsServiceImpl and @Component in WebSecurityConfig, same exception, dang...

Comment: Did you put `@ComponentScan` annotation? Your exception tell that, application context can't instantiate the bean or doesn't mark as bean. Spring component scanner can not discover the spring fundamental component.

Comment: @mangrove108 No need to swear. Please edit or delete and recreate your comment.

Comment: nope, nothing happened :-( same exception

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more easier with spring data you already load it with maven and this is a good step, now you should use it.
    don't creat you repository based on session factory but based on spring data like this.

```
    @Repository public interface AccountRepository extends 
 JpaRepository<AccountEntity, String>  {

            AccountEntity findByEmail(String username);

            AccountEntity findByName(String name);

        }
```

now you can @Autowired it where you want (you don't need any implementations, he understand that AccountEntity is the entity and it have Email and name as an attribute and you need to search by them ^^ )

its well documented   if you need any other future

Comment: i gave up switched to PHP 